# Is there "any" advantage in using "hexadecimals" for calculation instead of using 'big numbers"?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, bignumber, hex

I would like to know if there is "any" advantage, like speed of execution for example by using "Hexadecimals" instead of "big numbers"? If so can you please tell the advantages or disadvantages if any (Except for human readability of course)?

For instance since you will have to use a utils like

```
web3.utils.isBN(bn)
```

Would that not add an additional execution that would be slower then hex?

Comment: talking about speed of execution in JavaScript enironment doesn't make any sense. Javascript is an interpreted language and it is not designed for speed. It makes sense talking about performance in golang or Rust. The EVM (golang) uses fixed size 256 bit integer (github.com/holiman/uint256) , there are other fixed size big integer implementations out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum safe integer value that Javascript can handle is `9007199254740991`. You can check that by printing the result of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in Javascript.

`9007199254740991` is a 53-bit number. You can convert it to binary and count the number of bits it has on here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html

Decimal: `9007199254740991`

Binary: `11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Hexadecimal: `1FFFFFFFFFFFFF`

The maximum integer value that Solidity can handle is a 256-bit number:

Decimal: `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`

Binary: `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Hexadecimal: `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

So, if you want to safely handle integer numbers greater than a 53 bits, then you are better off using Big Integer instead of decimal or hex. Big Integers can handle any number, since they are not represented a usual bits, which is limited to the processor architecture. But rather are handled as strings and/or array of different parts and they use complex algorithms to handle them.

If you know that the values you are handling are small enough, then you could say there is some advantage using decimals and/or hex values in the calculation, since the Big Number abstraction will be a little more costly. But if you are on doubt, better use the Big Number, since with this you are going to be sure that it will work for all your cases.

Javascript does support Big Integers natively. You just need to use the `BigInt` class or append an `n` to a decimal number. For example:

```js
const _256BitMaxValueBigNumber = BigInt("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935");
```

And to do any operation with it, you will need another `BigInt`:

```js
const anotherBigInt = 500n; // Notice the `n` at the end, it's the same as BigInt('500')
```

Then we can multiply them:

```js
const result = _256BitMaxValueBigNumber * anotherBigInt;

console.log('result: ', result);
```

And the result is another `BigInt` (notice the `n` at the end of the number):

```js
57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967500n
```

But when working with `Web3`, you are better off using the `web3.utils.isBN` utility function that is designed to handle these blockchain related values.